# I want an object rotation around a circle on button click around certain degree .How to fix it

Tags: javascript

I want to rotate the circle around another circle with a certain degree on button click but it doesn't happen with button click here is the code with the mouse click. Please help me out how can i rotate a circle around another circle with a button on a certain degree. Here is the code How can it happen so that the rotator works fine.

```
<div id="picker">
<div id="picker-circle">
</div></div><img id="image1" src="Images/Homepage/apartment-architecture-ceiling-271724-min.jpg">`enter code here`<input type="text" id="circle_rot">
```

```js
<script>
 var circle = document.getElementById('circle'),
  picker = document.getElementById('picker'),
  pickerCircle = picker.firstElementChild,
  rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect(),
  center = {
   x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
   y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
  },

  transform = (function() {
   var prefs = ['t', 'WebkitT', 'MozT', 'msT', 'OT'],
    style = document.documentElement.style,
    p
   for (var i = 0, len = prefs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ((p = prefs[i] + 'ransform') in style) return p
   }

   alert('your browser doesnot support css transforms!')
  })(),

  rotate = function(x, y) {
   var deltaX = x - center.x,
    deltaY = y - center.y,

    // The atan2 method returns a numeric value between -pi and pi representing the angle theta of an (x,y) point.
    // This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x,y).
    // Note that the arguments to this function pass the y-coordinate first and the x-coordinate second.
    // atan2 is passed separate x and y arguments, and atan is passed the ratio of those two arguments.
    // * from Mozilla's MDN

    // Basically you give it an [y, x] difference of two points and it give you back an angle
    // The 0 point of the angle is left (the initial position of the picker is also left)

    angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI

   // Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) => [-PI +PI]
   // We must convert it to deg so...
   // / Math.PI => [-1 +1]
   // * 180 => [-180 +180]

   return angle
  },

  // DRAGSTART
  mousedown = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   document.body.style.cursor = 'move'
   mousemove(event)
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
  },

  // DRAG
  mousemove = function(event) {
   picker.style[transform] = 'rotate(' + rotate(event.pageX, event.pageY) + 'deg)'
   //     alert(picker.style[transform]);
   $('#circle_rot').val(picker.style[transform]);

  },

  // DRAGEND
  mouseup = function() {
   document.body.style.cursor = null;
   document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
   document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
  }



 // DRAG START
 pickerCircle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown)

 // ENABLE STARTING THE DRAG IN THE BLACK CIRCLE
 circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.target == this) mousedown(event)

 })
</script>
```

```html
<div id="picker">
 <div id="picker-circle">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<img id="image1" src="Images/Homepage/apartment-architecture-ceiling-271724-min.jpg">
<input type="text" id="circle_rot">
```

```
enter code here

var circle = document.getElementById('circle'),
    picker = document.getElementById('picker'),
    pickerCircle = picker.firstElementChild,
    rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect(),
    center = {
        x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
        y: rect.top + rect.height / 2,
    },

    transform = (function() {
        var prefs = ['t', 'WebkitT', 'MozT', 'msT', 'OT'],
            style = document.documentElement.style,
            p
        for (var i = 0, len = prefs.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ((p = prefs[i] + 'ransform') in style) return p
        }

        alert('your browser doesnot support css transforms!')
    })(),

    rotate = function(x, y) {
        var deltaX = x - center.x,
            deltaY = y - center.y,

            // The atan2 method returns a numeric value between -pi and pi representing the angle theta of an (x,y) point.
            // This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x,y).
            // Note that the arguments to this function pass the y-coordinate first and the x-coordinate second.
            // atan2 is passed separate x and y arguments, and atan is passed the ratio of those two arguments.
            // * from Mozilla's MDN

            // Basically you give it an [y, x] difference of two points and it give you back an angle
            // The 0 point of the angle is left (the initial position of the picker is also left)

            angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI

        // Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) => [-PI +PI]
        // We must convert it to deg so...
        // / Math.PI => [-1 +1]
        // * 180 => [-180 +180]

        return angle
    },

    // DRAGSTART
    mousedown = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        document.body.style.cursor = 'move'
        mousemove(event)
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
    },

    // DRAG
    mousemove = function(event) {
        picker.style[transform] = 'rotate(' + rotate(event.pageX, event.pageY) + 'deg)'
        //                  alert(picker.style[transform]);
        $('#circle_rot').val(picker.style[transform]);

    },

    // DRAGEND
    mouseup = function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = null;
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
    }



// DRAG START
pickerCircle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown)

// ENABLE STARTING THE DRAG IN THE BLACK CIRCLE
circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    if (event.target == this) mousedown(event)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('picker-circle'), //CHANGED
  picker = document.getElementById('picker'),
  rect = picker.getBoundingClientRect(), //CHANGED
    //REMOVED
  center = {
   x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
   y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
  },

  transform = (function() {
   var prefs = ['t', 'WebkitT', 'MozT', 'msT', 'OT'],
    style = document.documentElement.style,
    p
   for (var i = 0, len = prefs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ((p = prefs[i] + 'ransform') in style) return p
   }

   alert('your browser doesnot support css transforms!')
  })(),

  rotate = function(x, y) {
   var deltaX = center.x-x,
    deltaY = center.y-y,

    // The atan2 method returns a numeric value between -pi and pi representing the angle theta of an (x,y) point.
    // This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x,y).
    // Note that the arguments to this function pass the y-coordinate first and the x-coordinate second.
    // atan2 is passed separate x and y arguments, and atan is passed the ratio of those two arguments.
    // * from Mozilla's MDN

    // Basically you give it an [y, x] difference of two points and it give you back an angle
    // The 0 point of the angle is left (the initial position of the picker is also left)

    angle = (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) - Math.PI/4) * (180 / Math.PI) //CHANGED

   // Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) => [-PI +PI]
   // We must convert it to deg so...
   // / Math.PI => [-1 +1]
   // * 180 => [-180 +180]

   return angle
  },

  // DRAGSTART
  mousedown = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   document.body.style.cursor = 'move'
   mousemove(event)
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
  },

  // DRAG
  mousemove = function(event) {
   picker.style[transform] = 'rotate(' + rotate(event.pageX, event.pageY) + 'deg)'
   //     alert(picker.style[transform]);
   $('#circle_rot').val(picker.style[transform]);

  },

  // DRAGEND
  mouseup = function() {
   document.body.style.cursor = null;
   document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
   document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
  }



 // DRAG START
 circle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown); //CHANGED

 // ENABLE STARTING THE DRAG IN THE BLACK CIRCLE
 circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.target == this) mousedown(event)

 })
```

```css
#picker {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
#picker-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picker">
 <div id="picker-circle">
 </div>
</div>

<img id="image1" src="Images/Homepage/apartment-architecture-ceiling-271724-min.jpg">
<input type="text" id="circle_rot">
```

Comment: NO this is with a mouse for laptop devices I want it to be with touch or mobile devices.How can i use the touch event with this

Comment: Change mouse events to touch events and get the location of the touch event instead of mouse down event